# Definition of obtaining a copy of $l^{\infty}(2)$

Tags: definition, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, isometry

Currently I am reading the book 'Isometries on Banach Spaces: Vector-Valued function spaces and operator spaces.'

In chapter $7$ page $16,$ the author stated that:

> $Y$ does not contain a copy of real $l^{\infty}(2)$  if and only if at least one of the norms $\| x \pm y \| <2$ whenever $\| x \| = \| y \|=1.$

Question: What is the definition of not containing a copy of $l^{\infty}(2)?$ Also, what is $l^{\infty}(2)?$

I search it on the internet but fail to obtain its definition.

Answer (score 4):

$l^\infty_2$, $l^\infty(2)$ (or $\ell_\infty^2$ in certain circles including mine) is $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or $\mathbb{C}^2$ if you prefer complex scalars) endowed with the maximum norm. More generally, $\ell_p^n$ stands for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the $p$-norm. Curiously, the spaces $\ell_\infty^2$ and $\ell_1^2$ are isometric. This is no longer the case in higher dimensions.

By saying that a Banach space $X$ *does not contain* $\ell_p^n$ people usually mean that $\ell_p^n$ is not **isometric** to a subspace of $X$.

Answer (score 2):

It means that it does not contain a subspace isomorphic to $l^\infty (2)$

Comment: May I know what is $l^{\infty}(2)?$ I know the bounded sequence space $l^{\infty}$ but have no idea on what is $l^{\infty}(2)$?

Comment: I think it is the space of sequences that are bounded in absolute value by $2$, I think you should check whether that makes sense within the theorem.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I am afraid you are mistaken.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks Tomek, although I see no reason to delete my answer as it does in fact mean that. ( I just didn't happen to know what $l_2^\inf$ was, but that's ok):