# How to show a space contains an isometric copy of $\ell^{\infty}(2)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Continue the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2306610/definition-of-obtaining-a-copy-of-l-infty2).

> Question: To show that a banach space $E$ contains an isometric copy of $\ell^{\infty}(2),$ is it enough to show that there exists $e_1,e_2 \in E$ with $\| e_1\| = \|e_2\|=1$ such that for any $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R},$ $\|\alpha e_1 + \beta e_2 \| \leq \max\{ |\alpha|,|\beta|\}?$

Answer (score 0):

No, it means that $E $ has elements $e_1$ and $e_2$ such that  $$ \|\alpha e_1+\beta e_2\|=\max\{|\alpha|,|\beta|\}$$ for all coefficients $\alpha $ and $\beta $.

Comment: Isn't the norm a sup-norm? Shouldn't we get $\| \alpha e_1 + \beta e_2\| = \max\{ |\alpha|, |\beta| \}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thanks for your instant feedback. To show the equality, is it enough to show only $\| \alpha e_1 + \beta e_2\| \leq \max \{ |\alpha|,\beta \}?$

Comment: So you are saying that $\|\alpha e_1 + \beta e_2 \| \leq \max\{|\alpha|, |\beta| \}$ as long as $\| e_1\| \leq 1$ and $\| e_2\| \leq 1$?

Comment: no the inequality is not true in any banach space.. consider two orthonormal vectors in a hilbert space, for example

Comment: @user363464: I do not understand your statement. Consider $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1).$ Then $\| \alpha e_1 + \beta e_2\| = \| (\alpha,\beta)\| = \max\{ |\alpha|,|\beta|  \}$. I do not see any abnormality. Can you elaborate more on your statement?

Comment: $\lVert e_{1}+e_{2}\rVert^{2}=1^{2}+1^{2}$ by orthonormality

Comment: But the norm here is sup-norm, not $\ell^2$ norm.

Comment: the claim was that the inequality holds in any Banach space, this is not true in any Hilbert space (which are Banach spaces) (or in any inner product space of at least two dimensions, for that matter)

Comment: My comment was off. But I still don't see why the inequality would imply the equality.

Comment: @MartinArgerami you're right, the inequality does not imply equality since positive scaling of norms yields norms, so you can scale the sup norm by 1/2, for example